# Hosting the android mobile app in cloud server

Tags: php, android, amazon-ec2

I have developed an android app with the back end server in php using phpadmin.Now i want to export tables and the scripts to the server. I have following questions

1. Should i choose a cloud server like amazon ec2 or rack space or host ? I hosted a   website previously , would it be the same way ?
2. I am using google api,GCM in my app, would they work without any issues ?

Please help in clarifying my questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im developing an app in html5 for android and ios and im going to host it in cloud, probably with amazon.
With cloud you will pay what you really use. With traditional hosting you pay a fixed amount a year/month regardless your app is being used or not.
Cloud is dynamic, so if suddenly your app becomes populuar your app will still work fine because the cloud provider will give more resources.
Ill try amazon because its free under a certain amount of resources demand.

For the second question i think there are no problems with these apis.

Answer (score 0):

Android apps like

Connectbot
Overlook Whiz 
Magic Color Picker skyvi

Ping & DNS is a DNS and WHOIS lookup tool that displays network diagnostics, pings servers, DNS lookup and reverse lookup, WHOIS queries, inspects HTTP response headers, traces routes, and checks whether a port is open. All of this is provided with no advertisements in sight!